# Efficiently create pairs of people from a list with the condition that they've never been paired before

Tags: r, list, combinations

I have a list with `n` names: `sample = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']`

I also have a list of pairs that these are NOT allowed to pair, let's say `sample2 = [['a', 'e'], ['e', 'g'], ['b', 'a']]`

I would like an efficient way of randomly creating pair list from `sample` to get a list, given that they don't exist in `sample2`, such as: `newlist = [['a', 'h'], ['b', 'g'], ['f', 'c'], ['e', 'd']]`.

**Each element need to appear once, and only once, in the paired list.**

I have seen answers from this post [Efficiently pair random elements of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56156741/efficiently-pair-random-elements-of-list), which is done in Python and doesn't have the addition requirements that the pairs in sample2 must not appear.

EDIT 1:
What I have tried so far is to just use the `sample()` function and create two sets of data by cutting the `randomised` list in half, I then verify this against the `sample2`. If a pair exist in sample2, it loops again with the `sample()` function. I have used 26 for the iteration, but the list of names and the list of rule (`sample2`) is getting much bigger, resulting in longer runtime. So I was wondering if there is a better, efficient way of doing things.

The code chunk is as the following - (note that `name_data` is the `sample` list above)

```
sumcheck <- rep(1, 26)
while (sum(sumcheck) > 0) {
  
  randomised <- sample(name_data$ID)
  setone <- randomised[1:(length(randomised)/2)]
  settwo <- randomised[(length(randomised)/2 + 1) : length(randomised)]
  
  matches <- data.frame(setone, settwo)
  combination <- as.character(with(matches, interaction(setone,settwo)))
  combinationreverse <- as.character(with(matches, interaction(settwo,setone)))
  
  sumcheck <- (append(combination %in% sample2, combinationreverse %in% sample2))*1
}
```

Comment: It would be straightforward to generate random pairs using the sample() function, then filter out any forbidden pair using base R bracket notation or dplyr filter(). Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: @BillO'Brien I have updated the post with what I've tried, which is just using the sample() function.

Answer (score 0):

This generates random matches from the list of eligible letters, then filters out the bad combinations. You would probably want to improve this by keeping only distinct valid matches, and accounting for reversed order in the forbidden list.

```
set.seed(3)
people <- letters[1:4]
forbidden <- list(c('a', 'd'), c('a', 'b'), c('a', 'c'))

potentials <- lapply(1:5, function(x) c(sample(people, 1), sample(people, 1)))
matches <- potentials[!potentials %in% forbidden]

matches
[[1]]
[1] "d" "c"

[[2]]
[1] "d" "b"

[[3]]
[1] "d" "c"

[[4]]
[1] "c" "d"
```

Comment: Thanks for this Bill. if I understand the `lapply` function correctly, it creates a list of 5 and takes sample from the source list one at a time. So this means that it could pair the same person (i.e. `c('a', 'a')`) and it could create non-distinct matches like you've mentioned in the original post? 
I guess this is not too dissimilar to what I had originally done, ignorant of the runtime between the two, is there a better way of doing this to further improve runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `setdiff` + `combn` like below

```
setdiff(
    unlist(
        c(combn(sample1, 2, function(...) list(list(...), list(rev(...))))),
        recursive = FALSE
    ),
    sample2
)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b"

[[2]]
[1] "a" "c"

[[3]]
[1] "c" "a"

[[4]]
[1] "a" "d"

[[5]]
[1] "d" "a"

[[6]]
[1] "e" "a"

[[7]]
[1] "a" "f"

[[8]]
[1] "f" "a"

[[9]]
[1] "a" "g"

[[10]]
[1] "g" "a"

[[11]]
[1] "a" "h"

[[12]]
[1] "h" "a"

[[13]]
[1] "b" "c"

[[14]]
[1] "c" "b"

[[15]]
[1] "b" "d"

[[16]]
[1] "d" "b"

[[17]]
[1] "b" "e"

[[18]]
[1] "e" "b"

[[19]]
[1] "b" "f"

[[20]]
[1] "f" "b"

[[21]]
[1] "b" "g"

[[22]]
[1] "g" "b"

[[23]]
[1] "b" "h"

[[24]]
[1] "h" "b"

[[25]]
[1] "c" "d"

[[26]]
[1] "d" "c"

[[27]]
[1] "c" "e"

[[28]]
[1] "e" "c"

[[29]]
[1] "c" "f"

[[30]]
[1] "f" "c"

[[31]]
[1] "c" "g"

[[32]]
[1] "g" "c"

[[33]]
[1] "c" "h"

[[34]]
[1] "h" "c"

[[35]]
[1] "d" "e"

[[36]]
[1] "e" "d"

[[37]]
[1] "d" "f"

[[38]]
[1] "f" "d"

[[39]]
[1] "d" "g"

[[40]]
[1] "g" "d"

[[41]]
[1] "d" "h"

[[42]]
[1] "h" "d"

[[43]]
[1] "e" "f"

[[44]]
[1] "f" "e"

[[45]]
[1] "g" "e"

[[46]]
[1] "e" "h"

[[47]]
[1] "h" "e"

[[48]]
[1] "f" "g"

[[49]]
[1] "g" "f"

[[50]]
[1] "f" "h"

[[51]]
[1] "h" "f"

[[52]]
[1] "g" "h"

[[53]]
[1] "h" "g"
```

**Data**

```
sample1 <- letters[1:8]
sample2 <- list(c("a", "e"), c("e", "g"), c("b", "a"))
```