# Create unique random pairs from list, with reference to previous pairings

Tags: r

I am organising a coffee meet up group, where each month every person on a list is randomly paired with another person on the list. There are numerous Q&A related to generating random pairs from a list in R, but none that meet all the functional criteria I am looking for.

I want to create unique random pairs from a list of names multiple times in R (e.g. monthly), with a way of ensuring that with each iteration there is not a duplicate pair produced. This means I need with each iteration be able to read in previously generated pairing lists for R to compare against when generating a new list of unique pairs.

The list of names will also increase over time, so I can't simply produce a list of all possible pairings at the beginning and then select from that.

Data is in a simple format:

```
names <- c("John", "Fiona", "Abdul", "Mishra", "Sven", "Bianka")
```

I was unable to find R code online that would address all of the points above - not yet experienced enough to try and solve this without some help!

Comment: the `names` object you shared is a vector, not  a list. In addition, `names` is already a predefined function in R so it is recommended not to use it for naming objects

Comment: Maybe try: `combn(LETTERS[1:5], 2)`

Comment: Please provide expected output.

Comment: Thanks Sotos for your comments. My understanding @zx8754 is that combn(LETTERS[1:5], 2) would provide all possible combinations of names in the list - what I need is a process to produce a single combination of pairs for all individuals in the list (if 50 individuals, then 25 pairs), but be able to iteratively produce new lists of unique pairs with no duplication from previous lists.

Comment: The input data could be in a vector or in a data frame with a single variable, the expected output should be a vector of paired values, or could be a data frame with two variables that comprise the first and second names for each pair.

Comment: There's simply no efficient algorithm for creating such pairings. Seems related to the [social golfer problem](https://www.mathpuzzle.com/MAA/54-Golf%20Tournaments/mathgames_08_14_07.html). But even in those cases the people are the same each time; it's even harder if you have different sets of people each round. How many people does it have to scale to? You could try an algorithm where you pair off the most "constrained" individuals first but you'd probably have to account for backtracking or decide what you want to do when "impossible" situations arise

Comment: It seems I'm not the first person to be puzzled by this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68442680/efficiently-create-pairs-of-people-from-a-list-with-the-condition-that-theyve-n?rq=2 I got their first block of code (added to the question) to run, but it didn't exclude reverse pairings from the sample2 list (i.e. I want to exclude the pair 'A and B' and it's reverse 'B and A').

Comment: @MrFlick so far I have 48 people on my list, but I expect that to grow to 100-200 in time. I feel like the approach in the link above should work but the final line  sumcheck <- (append(combination %in% sample2, combinationreverse %in% sample2))*1 doesn't appear to work to exclude reverse combinations of forbidden pairs

Comment: I'm not sure how you created `sample2` in your own code. Is it also the result of an `interaction()`? But the problem with that solution is it's not guaranteed to ever exit that loop. If you naively sample from the (very large) sample space, it's becomes increasingly unlikely you'll find a plausible configuration are time goes on.